# jsonschema: Add Warnings / Deprecation to Schema

Tags: warnings, deprecated, jsonschema, deprecation-warning

In many schemas, you may want to deprecate fields and log warnings when these fields are used without causing a validation to fail entirely. Is there any way or a preferred way to do this in jsonschema? From what I've read, it seems all or nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `draft-7` JSON Schema, you'll have to add your own keyword and your own hook / plugin to do whatever you want to do.

For draft `2019-09` JSON Schema, we added the `deprecated` annotation keyword.

Annotations don't "do" anything, but provide a way for you to create (or use) other tooling which relies on standardised keywords to perform other actions.

Implementations that support annotation collection will provide you with the data you require to post process results and perform action as appropriate.

There's no "plug and play" solution to what you're asking, as far as I know.