# JsonSchema logging deprecated warnings to schema

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I want to log a warning when a deprecated property is being used or when the value of that property is in a deprecated format. I'm using the `deprecated` annotation for that but it doesn't do anything. I stumbled on this similar question [jsonschema: Add Warnings / Deprecation to Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805654/jsonschema-add-warnings-deprecation-to-schema) It says I can use implementations that support annotation collection, but I don't know how to do it. I would appreciate any examples on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every implementations upports annotations. I don't believe there is one currently in Python.
You can see an example of the collected annotations being provided by using the JSON Everyting JSON Schema playground: https://json-everything.net/json-schema/